# Pandas dataframe sort_values not working on very large integers

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, ubuntu, dataframe

I have scenario in which I have very last bit string which represents very large integers. Dataframe sort values does not seem to work with very large numbers.

E.g

```
import pandas

collection = [{'val1': 1, 'val2': 21267647942462174285355641184253378561}, {'val1': 2, 'val2': 42535295884924348570711282368506757122}]
df = pandas.DataFrame(collection)
result_job_order = df.sort_values(by=["val1", "val2"],ascending=[False, False])
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3139, in sort_values
    na_position=na_position)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 4128, in _lexsort_indexer
    c = Categorical(key, ordered=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/categorical.py", line 298, in __init__
    categories = self._validate_categories(categories)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/categorical.py", line 487, in _validate_categories
    categories = Index(categories, dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 232, in __new__
    return Int64Index(subarr.astype('i8'), copy=copy,
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

How can I solve this issue?

Any other alternative for for sorting values?

I do 11 level sorting on a dataset of 1000 element array.
I need this to work at massive speed since entire point of converting 
to binary numbers instead of string combinations was to achieve massive speed.

Very strange This particular issue a happens on my ubuntu server which is a 64 bit c4.large machine but does not happen on my macbook.

Comment: If you read the data into a list, are you still not able to sort?

Comment: Actually, if you use `import sys`; `sys.maxsize > <your values>`  you'll see that the issue (as indicated by the `OverflowError`) shows the integers are too large for Python, or your machine

Comment: Thanks Worked For me

Answer (score 0):

As Scot mentioned in comments, 
using `float` for very large number it worked for me

```
collection = [{'val1': 1, 'val2': 21267647942462174285355641184253378561*1.0}, 
              {'val1': 2, 'val2': 42535295884924348570711282368506757122*1.0}]
```

Also as an alternative for sorting

```
sorted(collection, key=lambda x: (-x['val1'], -x['val2']))
```

Comment: Be very careful changing the values to floats, you will find that you lose precision and some number will not be different. Try this is python to see what I mean int(float(12345678901234567))